# Retrieve current working directory in axis2.xml

Tags: tomcat, servlets, apache-axis

I am stuck in a issue from past few days where am not able to retrieve the current working directory of my AXIS2_HOME directory in WEB-INF\conf\axis2.xml.

I have tried inserting the AXIS2_HOME property in tomcat/bin/setenv.bat file, but no success

```
<parameter name="Custom-XML-Listener">
  <parameter name="services" 
  location="${AXIS2_HOME}\WEB-INF\services"/> 
  </parameter>
```

I am expecting AXIS2_HOME property value in my axis2.xml. Can tomcat/axis2 experts  please guide me on this issue.

I am a beginner, please forgive any formatting issues or might be a dumb question.

Comment: Does this help https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/How-to-setup-Tomcat-environment-variables

Comment: I did that..Adding the AXIS2_HOME variable in Tomcat setEnv.sh file.. But no success

Comment: Try this ${env.AXIS2_HOME}